# Accessing A Local IP Address Globally Through a Static IP Using a Web Browser

Tags: networking, web-development

I'm trying to setup an Ubuntu server for my daily Web developments. Now that I run the code the framework puts the deployment (HTTP server that holds the web service) on a local address: `127.0.0.0:89`. If the static address of my server is `99.99.99.99`, is there a way I can access to the local deployment, globally, through a browser?

I can't go simply to `99.99.99.99:89` because obviously that port is not recognized/opened globally. The only port that can be used on a browser by default is the HTTP port which is by default 80.

Comment: As you noted, `127.0.0.0` is a local address. You should bind to a public address, or to `0.0.0.0` (all ipv4 network interfaces).

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Thank you for the pointer, I would appreciate it, if you could write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, `127.0.0.0` is a local address. You should bind to a public address, or to `0.0.0.0` (all ipv4 network interfaces).

Comment: As I don't want to open any port 24/7 just for deployment, is there a way I can temporary open the port, through the terminal, and route it to the public address?

Comment: Well, it really depends on your preferences and on your setup. You may change the bind address to `0.0.0.0` temporarily and restart the webserver. If you have a router, you may open/close the port as required. You may set up a [transparent proxy with iptables](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy-5.html). There are many more options, but again, it's difficult to tell what would work best.